# Is there a function for drupal that can identity if a certain page and its children are being viewed?

Tags: paging, views

So I have nav that looks like this:

```
<li>
  <a href="/some-parent-url">Parent Url</>
  <ul>
    <li>
       <a href="/some-parent-url/child-url-2">Child Url</a> 
    </li>
    <li>
       <a href="/some-parent-url/child-url-2">Child Url</a> 
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

I would like to add an "active" class to the Parent URl if a user is on the page with url "some-parent-url" or any of it's parent url?

Ideally something like

```
<a href="/some-parent-url" <?php if (some_drupal_code_for_this){ echo 'class="active"'; } ?>>Parent Url</>
```

Comment: Why to not use [theme_menu_link](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/function/theme_menu_link/7) for that? There you can check each element by depth: `$element = $variables['element']; $depth = $element['#original_link']['depth'];` In your code the parent url would have depth = 1, child-url-2 = 2, child-url-3 = 3. Use [l() function](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/l/7) to create links, it takes care about "active" class.

Comment: I have update my answer without using any **CONTRIBUTE** modules. It can be achieve programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Menu Trail By Path](https://drupal.org/project/menu_trail_by_path) module.

> Menu Trail By Path sets the active-trail on menu items according to
>   the current url.

For example if you are at yoursite.com/blog/category1/article1
Menu Items with these paths will get the active-trail class on them and expand accordingly.

Comment: I was trying to do without using a module.

Answer (score 1):

In Drupal 7, you can achieve this by using contributed modules and also by programatically.

**Using [Context](https://drupal.org/project/context) module**.

- Go to admin » structure »context » add
- While adding new context go to **Conditions** category and click **<add a condition>** and select **PATH** in the list and add **YOUR_PATH**.

  [image]
- Now its time to ACTIVE the MENU. Go to **Reactions** category and click **<add a reaction>** and and select **MENU** in the list. And select the MENU which you want to be active.

  [image]
- For this example I have selected **Article** as an active menu item.

  [image]
- I have made **Article** as an active menu item for the following contexts. Each contexts  have different path, but have same active menu item.

  [image]

**Programatically** :

- By using [menu_get_active_trail](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/function/menu_get_active_trail/7) and [menu_set_active_item](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/function/menu_set_active_trail/7) we can achieve it
- **menu_get_active_trail** - To gets the active trail of the current page.
- **menu_set_active_item** - To sets the active trail of the current page.

  function THEMENAME_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
      $trail = menu_get_active_trail();//get the active menu trail
          if (count($trail) >= 3) {//if there are children menu items
          menu_set_active_item($trail[1]['link_path']);//set the active menu
      }
  }

Answer (score 0):

If this isn't a menu you may want to use [Drupal args](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/arg/7) and check if your anchor's URL equals the args.
If this is a menu consider to use menu_get_active_trail() .

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Crumbs](http://drupal.org/project/crumbs) + [Menupoly](http://drupal.org/project/menupoly).

With Crumbs, you make sure that any child page where you want the parent item to be highlighted is in the breadcrumb.

With Menupoly, you can display a menu, where items are expanded and highlighted if they are in the Crumbs breadcrumb trail, even if the current page is not in the menu.

E.g. if the menu only goes as deep as "Parent > Child", but your page is at "Parent > Child > Grandchild > Grandgrandchild" (without being in any menu), then 
Menupoly would still expand / highlight the "Parent > Child" menu links in the menu.

So, the effect is similar to [Menu Trail By Path](https://drupal.org/project/menu_trail_by_path) as suggested by Nikhil M. You need to figure out which of them is more practical for your taste.

You need a little bit of programming to make the menupoly menu show up. This is explained on the module page.